# Complex Hölder space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, banach-spaces, ergodic-theory

I already posted this question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4413395/680679), but got no response and was suggested to post it here.

I came across a space in an ergodic theory paper, which I am calling here a (complex) Hölder space, because of the similarity to the usual [Hölder space](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_space).

Fix some open bounded convex set $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. For every $F:U \to B$, where $B$ is a Banach Space, set,
$$\lVert F \rVert_{\infty}=\sup_{z\in U} \lVert F(z)\rVert \qquad D_{\alpha} F=\sup_{0<|z-w|<1}\left\{\frac{\lVert F(z)-F(w)\rVert}{|z-w|^\alpha} \right\}$$

If $F$ is differentiable $r$ times, define

$$\lVert F\rVert_{r,\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^r \lVert F^{(k)}\rVert_{\infty} + D_\alpha F^{(r)}$$

In this case, the Hölder Space $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha}$ is the space of all $F:U\to B$ which are differetiable $r$-times in $U$ and for which $\lVert F\rVert_{r,\alpha}$ is finite. I found that definition [here](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/math/sarigo/sites/math.sarigo/files/uploads/decay5.pdf).

I'm having trouble finding a book that deals with this space. I can see that the real and complex case share several properties, but I would like some reference. I'm looking for any kind of reference, it can be books, articles or lecture notes... That discuss some properties of this space, from a more analytical point of view, I mean, properties of the functions of these spaces, relations between the spaces for different $r$'s...

I imagine this space can be thought of when considering $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I would like a reference to see certain specific features when we are dealing with complex functions...

I was able to find only one reference, which is the book "*Holomorphic Operator Functions of One Variable and Applications*" by I. Gohberg and J. Leiterer, the definition of this space is on page 33 and an image of this page can be [found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBu1A.png). The authors call this space the **Hölder-$\alpha$ continuous**, in addition to the discussions in the book not being exactly what I'm looking for, the norm is slightly different, the [uniform norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) is taken only on $F$ and not on its derivatives.

---

*The notation $F^{(r)}$, stands for the $r$ Frechet derivative of $F$.*

Comment: @WillieWong I discussed this briefly with OP in math.SE chat and suggested to post here, and scanning through [the paper OP saw this in](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/math/sarigo/sites/math.sarigo/files/uploads/decay5.pdf) I suspect this is a space of analytic functions which is Hölder continuous up to the boundary, so a subspace of the disk algebra if U was a disk? (wildly out of my comfort zone)

Comment: @WillieWong So, I thought the same, but when it says differentiable $r$-times it's not necessarily the last derivative, in this case, I believe that this restriction is given by the hölder constant. Or in this case, will all derivatives satisfy the fact that $D_\alpha F^{(r)}$ is finite?